# Valores em Json sem aspas duplas

Tags: php, json

Tenho um arquivo php/json em que os números vindo de uma consulta sql resultam em aspas duplas:

```
"relatorio": [
    "3",
    "1",
    "2"
]
```

Gostaria de deixa-las sem as aspas duplas nos números.
Estou usando uma consulta sql em php para exibir os resultados.

```
$check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as 'total' FROM rating WHERE rt_rating IS NOT NULL group by rt_rating");
$check->execute();
while ( $lista = $check->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ) )
{
    $out['relatorio'][] = $lista->total;
}
```

O que eu gostaria que resultado fosse semelhante a esse:

```
"relatorio3": [4,2,1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a constante `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` no `json_encode`:

```php
$resultado = json_encode($out, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Deu certo. muito obrigado :)